# How can I get the value of a TimePicker?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile, mvvm, timepicker

This screen consists of a form that will store the days of the week and their respective times when a sports court is open to the public.

The `HoraInicio` (initial time) and `HoraFim` (end time) properties are coming with the value `00: 00: 00`.

[Time picker debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGCqe.png)

[Time pickers screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1732s.png)

XAML

```cs
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Horarios}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="40">
                                    <Switch x:Name="AbertoSwitch"
                                            IsToggled="{Binding Aberto}"
                                            Toggled="AlteracaoDoEstadoDoSwitch"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding DiaDaSemanaText}"
                                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <TimePicker BindingContext="{x:Reference AbertoSwitch}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding IsToggled}"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                Format="HH:mm"
                                                Time="{Binding HoraInicio}"/>
                                    <TimePicker BindingContext="{x:Reference AbertoSwitch}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding IsToggled}"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                Format="HH:mm"
                                                Time="{Binding HoraFim}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Model

```cs
public class Horario
    {
        public Quadra Quadra { get; set; }
        public String HoraInicio { get; set; }
        public String HoraFim { get; set; }
        public int DiaDaSemana { get; set; }
        public Boolean Aberto { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String DiaDaSemanaText
        {
            get
            {
                if (DiaDaSemana == 0) return "Domingo";
                else if (DiaDaSemana == 1) return "Segunda-feira";
                else if (DiaDaSemana == 2) return "Terça-feira";
                else if (DiaDaSemana == 3) return "Quarta-feira";
                else if (DiaDaSemana == 4) return "Quinta-feira";
                else if (DiaDaSemana == 5) return "Sexta-feira";
                else return "Sábado";
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Horario> Horarios { get; set; }

public TimeSpan HoraInicio { get => horaInicio; set => SetProperty(ref horaInicio, value); }
public TimeSpan HoraFim { get => horaFim; set => SetProperty(ref horaFim, value); }

public QuadraCadastroViewModel()
        {
            Horarios = new ObservableCollection<Horario>
            {
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 0,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 1,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 2,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 3,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 4,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 5,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                },
                new Horario
                {
                    DiaDaSemana = 6,
                    HoraInicio = "",
                    HoraFim = "",
                    Aberto = false
                }
            };
        }

public void AtribuirHorarioParaCadaDiaDisponivel()
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
                {
                    if (this.Horarios[i].Aberto == true)
                    {
                        this.Horarios[i].HoraInicio = this.HoraInicio.ToString();
                        this.Horarios[i].HoraFim = this.HoraFim.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Horário(s) incorreto(s)");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are setting the BindingContext of  your pickers to AbertoSwitch, so that will break the binding expressions for Time.  Instead I would use a source on the IsVisible binding so that the binding context of the overall control does not change

Comment: @Jason I didn't know that one binding could lead to another. I'm thinking about how I could implement it using IsVisible

Comment: Could you provide more details for `Horarios`, `Aberto`? We need a code snippet to reproduce.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I added this missing information.

Comment: How do you binding the value for `IsVisible`? Why do not you binding the value in the same item source? According to the code, the TimePicker binding the value of `HoraFim`. Do you mean you do not get the value?